In Unity with C# 8, how to use reflection to set a mutable field value?
Here is a simple example:

    [System.Serializable]
    public struct PlayerData
    {
        public string name;
        public int level;
        public float health;
    }

        [Test]
        public void SetValue_ChangesHealthUsingReflection()
        {
            // Arrange
            var playerData = new PlayerData
            {
                name = "Test Player",
                level = 1,
                health = 100f
            };

            // Act
            var healthField = typeof(PlayerData).GetField("health");
            healthField.SetValue(playerData, 75.5f);

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(75.5f, playerData.health);
        }

It just fail silently, the value of playerData is still 100.0f.
What's the reason of this behaviour and how to fix it?

Mutating a struct, reflection or not, is a big no-no. I guess there is a hidden silent copy there, not changing what you think it changed.

that's interesting, I always thought only records are immutable :D

will verify and merge shortly

As @Alejandro says my guess would be pretty much that the paramter of healthField.SetValue(playerData, 75.5f); is passed by value and not by reference so the moment you call this method it is being executed on a copy of playerData (which is only then boxed into object) .. boxing manually beforehand solves this as that object is then a reference type .. is there a reason why use Reflection at all here? Tests should usually test public stuff and not go fizzling too much with privates ..
